# Index error while moving on a matrix object C++

Tags: c++, loops, matrix, while-loop, switch-statement

I am trying to fit a word to a matrix by iteration but when I enter a row = 0, the function tries to check  *arbit_mat[r][c - 1] == '-'* in the while loop and gives error. How can I fix this issue?

```
if (rotation == "CW")
    {
        switch (direction[0]) {
        case 'l':
            // left situation
            
            while ((c - 1 >= 0) & (arbit_mat[r][c - 1] == '-')) {
                arbit_mat[r][c - 1] = word[idx];
                idx++;
                c--;

                printMatrix(arbit_mat);

                if (idx == word.length())
                {
                    return arbit_mat;
                }
                if (c == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                
            }
```

I have written an if statement inside the loop to solve the problem but when the row starts with 0, it gives error of:

> Vector subscript out of range!

Thank you for contributing.

Comment: I posted an answer, using & vs &&, but there may be other errors with this code.  I don't have enough code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Also when you get the error, check the values of `r` and `c` to make sure they're sensible on the `arbit_mat[r][c - 1]` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
while ((c - 1 >= 0) && (arbit_mat[r][c - 1] == '-')) {
```

& is the bitwise and operator

&& is the logical and operator